# Can't start Application using Websphere 8.5.5, hibernate jpa 4.2.6, oracle 12c

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere-8, oracle12c, ojdbc

I have a problem that is freaking me out.

This is my persistence.xml, the persistence unit is correct.

```
<persistence-unit name="pu-administrativo" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/oracle</non-jta-data-source>

    <!-- Incluir Entidades -->
    <class>GrupoUsuario</class>
    <class>Dominio</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
            value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereJtaPlatform" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I configured hibernate and datasource in Websphere with OJDBC6.

I used to start normally the application before when I was using OJDBC14. But the database was moved to another IP and now I can't connect with the OJDBC14.

When I use the OJDBC6 the application does not start and freeze on this:

`[07/08/15 14:09:36:239 BRT] 0000006a ConnectionPro Z org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
[07/08/15 14:09:37:257 BRT] 0000006a InternalGener I   DSRA8203I: Nome do produto de banco de dados: Oracle
[07/08/15 14:09:37:265 BRT] 0000006a InternalGener I   DSRA8204I: Versão do produto Banco de Dados: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
[07/08/15 14:09:37:266 BRT] 0000006a InternalGener I   DSRA8205I: Nome do driver JDBC: Oracle JDBC driver
[07/08/15 14:09:37:266 BRT] 0000006a InternalGener I   DSRA8206I: Versão do driver JDBC: 11.2.0.4.0
[07/08/15 14:09:37:266 BRT] 0000006a InternalGener I   DSRA8218I: Nível de especificação do driver JDBC: 11.2
[07/08/15 14:09:37:266 BRT] 0000006a InternalOracl I   DSRA8212I: O nome do DataStoreHelper é: com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.Oracle11gDataStoreHelper.
[07/08/15 14:09:37:267 BRT] 0000006a WSRdbDataSour I   DSRA8208I: Tipo de driver JDBC: 4`

after 11 minutes of starting the application it shows this message

`WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 3" (0000007a) has been active for 703443 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.`

I already tried using OJDBC14 and OJDBC7 and dit not work

The server starts perfectly but when I try to start de application freezes. I think I have a problem with the application but I did not figure out yet.

Can you guys please help me?

- I can connect to the database in Websphere console (http://localhost:9060/ibm/console) perfectly. So its not a firewall problem.

Comment: `But the database was moved to another IP and now I can't connect with the OJDBC14` - Maybe there is some problem with firewall ? New IP, maybe new machine and you cant event get there. Propably port is cut down for you. Check it.

Comment: I tested the connection in websphere console and works perfectly. The problem is not this one.

Comment: @Felipe Lyra - Did you fix this already? If not I can try helping you to find the root cause that is causing the hung in that thread.

Comment: @MarcosMaia Didnt, how can you help me?

Comment: @FelipeLyra - You need to investigate why and where the thread is getting stuck. I would start there. My recommendation is that you take a look and run the tool (just a script you have to download) wait.ibm.com for like 3 to 5 minutes(it will collect a dump each 30s) and than upload the generated file to it's site. This will probably point out the stack where your thread is getting stuck and give you an initial investigation point to look for a fix.

Comment: @FelipeLyra - You can also download the use the ISA(IBM support Assistant) tool to investigate further. You can extract the thread dumps from the file WAIT tool generates and use the Thread Analyzer tool from ISA to see the threads in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the following Dialect?

org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect